# Web application and UTC Dates

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm battling with my model for storing dates in a web application used in different time zones. At the moment, all dates are stored in UTC dates. So, lets say I am allowing the user to save a Transaction date, and a field on the screen is "Transaction Date". I default it to DateTime.UTCNow. SQL Server is in the United States, and I am in Australia.

So, what I have done now, is when I present the default transaction date, I add the GMT Offset to the UTC Now date:

```
var usersCurrentDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(GmtOffset.Value);
```

Where GmtOffset is a value in seconds, difference from GMT.

This code works - the user get's presented with the current date/time in their zone.

My issue is - how I should store this. Going to the UI, I do the above conversion. Should I then have a converted on the way to the database that converts the date entered by the user, back into UTC date/time?

In that case, I am always sure that all dates in the database are UTC dates. And then when ever I get the data from the database, I need to remember to translate into Local time? So, have a function that takes a Local time (As entered by the user) and converts it to the UTC?

Something like:

```
public DateTime UserDateToUTC(DateTime userDate)
{
   return DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(GmtOffset.Value * -1);
}
```

Is this an acceptable pattern?

Comment: why not store as datetimeoffset() ?

Comment: The only way to do this properly is to serialize the DateTime to the client as a UTC DateTime i.e. with a 'Z' on the end. The user's browser obviously knows what timezone it is in and so it (via your javascript code - look at Moment.js) can display it the correct local time. The problem with storing the offset is that, in most countries, this will give you wrong local DateTimes, at different times of the year, due to daylight savings changes.